# nginx limiting the total cache size

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx to cache requests to my uwsgi backend using

```
uwsgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/uwsgi keys_zone=cache:15M max_size=5G;
```

My back-end is setting a very long expires header (1 year+).  However, as my system runs, I see the cache topping out at 15M.  It gets up to that level, then prunes down to 10M.

This causes a lot of unnecessary calls to my back end.  When I change the keys_zone size it seems to control the size of the entire cache.  It seems to ignore the max_size and instead substitute the keys_zone size. (*)

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is there a known bug in this version?  Am I missing the point?  I don't want to allocate 5G to the cache manager..

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.0
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module
```

(*)  Update: I guess this was my overactive imagination trying to find a pattern in the chaos.

Comment: By default, your inactive cache will be deleted after 10 min. Could you increase that number to see if it makes a difference? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path

Comment: I think you got it!  Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.  The docs aren't really that clear - I thought since I was using an expired header that would override the inactive parameter.  I should have tried it myself.

Comment: Right. Expires header (and some other headers) is honoured by nginx to determine if a response is cacheable, but it's not used to determine how long to cache it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expires header ([and some other headers](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache)) is honoured by nginx to determine if a response is cacheable, but it's not used to determine how long to cache it.

By default, your inactive cache will be deleted after 10 min. Could you increase that number to see if it makes a difference?

> proxy_cache_path path [levels=levels] keys_zone=name:size
>   [inactive=time] [max_size=size] [loader_files=number]
>   [loader_sleep=time] [loader_threshold=time];
>
> Cached data that are not accessed during the time specified by the
>   inactive parameter get removed from the cache regardless of their
>   freshness. By default, inactive is set to 10 minutes.

Reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path

Comment: Please can you show which part of the documentation says that the expires header is not used to determine how long to cache it?  I read _The cache honors backend's "Expires"_ as that it is honours the actual expiry date in the headers value when it caches it.  In other words, it will automatically invalidate it at the specified expiry time.